# Lower ceilings, shorter tenants

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The housing shortage was so acute that when a developer proposed to save space and money by constructing an apartment building with 6-foot ceilings, he was allowed to build it and the apartments were rented before it was finished. Succeeding generations were shorter and ceilings kept coming down in a vicious cycle. At the end of the story, people were proudly standing two feet tall and happy to have kept up with the rising population.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The Vision of Milty Boil](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?97358) by Howard Fast. I read it in his anthology [The General Zapped an Angel](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?40457).

The eponymous Milty Boil is the developer who manages to get the minimum ceiling height reduced:

> And Milty made friends and built influence. By 1975, at the age of thirty-five, he was considered the most influential man in New York City. His influence was such that he was able to have a number of significant changes made in the building code—among them the lowering of the minimum height of the ceilings to seven feet. With this achieved, he built the first one-hundred-story apartment house in New York. In 1980, riding the crest of the wave created by the population explosion, Milty Boil managed to have the city council pass an ordinance permitting ceilings of six feet in all apartment buildings over fifty stories high.

The story ends:

> But where is there a great man who has not suffered the barbs of envy and hatred? Slander is the burden the great must carry, and Milton Boil carried it as silently and patiently as any man.
> On the modest headstone that graces his final resting place, an epitaph written by Milty himself is carved:
> “He found them tall and left them small.”
> To which our generation, standing erect and proud under our three-foot ceilings, can only add a grateful amen.

Comment: Thank you. This is certainly the right story, though I don't seem to have read it in the anthologies listed in the ISFDB. Curious.